# How to set launch.json cwd property for multi-project .net core mvc app

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .net core MVC app that was originally created in Visual Studio in Windows. We also develop in Mac OS High Sierra, and I'm having difficulty setting up Visual Studio Code to properly debug the app. These are the aspects of the dillema:

1. This is a multi-project solution, so in order to run it under .NET Core, we must run the `dotnet run` command from the parent directory that contains the solution file. If we use the project directory instead, the dependencies don't build correctly
2. In Visual Studio code I can run the project if I set the `cwd` property in my `launch.json` configuration to the solution directory. If I use the project directory instead, we see the same dependency problem
3. If I set `cwd` to the solution directory, then that becomes the working directory of the running app, and configuration files aren't loaded correctly

What I need is a way to configure working directory of the app to the project directory, but still build the app from the parent, solution directory. I was hoping to find a way to specify a directory for the `preLaunchTask` separately, but I haven't found it.